# Error on oledb "INSERT INTO" statement

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a little project and I have to use an access database.
I have a big problem with the "INSERT INTO" statement, and again after many hours spent to find a solution.
This is a part of code :

```
     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        connexion.Open()
        Dim cmdString_update As String = "INSERT INTO notes (nom, note) VALUES (@nom, @note)"    
        Dim SQLCommand3 As New OleDbCommand(cmdString_update, connexion)
        SQLCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", nom)
        SQLCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", note)
        'SQLCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentaire", commentaire)
        SQLCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As OleDbException
        ' Display error
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        ' Close Connection
        connexion.Close()
        MsgBox("Connection Closed")
    End Try

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of the error : h[ttps://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3v4Tp1x6sfDMWFEQTJUbUVTTUE/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3v4Tp1x6sfDMWFEQTJUbUVTTUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Can you help me, please ? It's driving me very, very crazy !!

Thanks a lot, sorry for my bad english.

(I'm programming in VB.NET with Visual Studio Express 2012.)

Comment: Hmm...very sorry Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word NOTE is a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) in MS-Access.
To use that word with OleDb, you should change your query in this way...

```
 Dim cmdString_update = "INSERT INTO notes (nom, [note]) VALUES (@nom, @note)"
```

Adding  square brackets around the incriminated field will keep it safe from misunderstanding.
However, if it is still possible, try to change the field name to something else.
Otherwise you will have this problem every time your try to use the field.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. You help me a lot. Next time I will be more rigorous. But I'm very surprising that MS Access does not warn me about this protected work as it warn me in an other table.

Comment: Usually, on the C# side, you get back an exception saying "Syntax Error in Insert....". I agree that is a little confusing.